# setup to allow third party cookies while invoking a browser using playwright

Tags: playwright

How to **enable third party cookies while invoking chrome incognito using playwright automation** tool?

I couldn't able to find a solution for this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread, it is apparently not currently possible with Playwright: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11072

> We don't have a feature that enables all cookies in Chrome, we only use default settings.